# Java - closing frame

Tags: java, frame

From first frame I call another frame:

```
frame2 fr2 = new frame2();
fr2.setVisible(true);
```

but when I'm trying to close in the same way - no reaction

```
frame2 fr2 = new frame2();
fr2.setVisible(false);
```

All that I do using two buttons on first frame

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
frame2 fr2 = new frame2();
fr2.setVisible(false);
```

by this, you are creating a new instance of frame2 and hiding it and you are not doing anything to the frame2 instance that you have already created and  hence `no reaction`

What you should do is create a class field or something similar to hold reference to the instance of frame2 you create at first (when you show it) and then use the same reference and call `setVisible(false)`.

```
class frame1{
    ...

    private frame2 frame2ref;
    ....


    void foo()
    {
       ....
       frame2ref = new frame2();
       frame2ref .setVisible(true);
       // create and save reference and show frame.
       ...
    }

    void bar()
    {
        ...
        frame2ref.setVisible(false);
        // retrieve reference and hide frame. 
        ...

    }

}
```